# How to move the 'clear results' button to the results in Google's CSE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-custom-search

How can I move the *clear results* button to the results section? [I found this answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/KT7SQA_h33A) but it's for a different or older search version and I can't seem to be able to get the same concept to work on this version of the custom search.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
google.load('search', '1', {language: 'en'});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchOptions = {};
    var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('{param_id}', customSearchOptions);
    var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    options.setAutoComplete(true);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
    jQuery('input.gsc-input').val('Search');
}, true);
</script>
```

I've tried this `jQuery('td.gsc-clear-button').insertAfter(jQuery('.gsc-above-wrapper-area'));` to try and move the clear button to the search results but nothing happened.

I was able to add placeholder text with `jQuery('input.gsc-input').val('Search');` but changing the clear button apparently isn't as simple.

I'll ask this on Google's help forums as well to see if someone has an answer there. If they do, I'll be sure to add it here.

Comment: Do you want help with this?

Answer (score 0):

To grab the clear results button:

```
var $grabClearResults = $('.gsib_b');
```

Then to place the button into the results:

```
jQuery('.gsc-result-info-container').after($grabClearResults);
```